# how can i use UISCrollView paging with different heights?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UIScrollView which shows multiple images when user swipe horizontally. But these images does not have the same height. The first image has height taller then the second.

1.What I want to do is when the person swipes, the next picture shown, is positioned at the top.

2.Also when using ScrollView's paging, the vertical scrolling is not smooth, it skips a whole frame. I've read that i cannot use ScrollView's paging to get the vertical scrolling smooth.

Any ideas?

For the 1st problem should I load nibs with images inside? How do I load a nib after swiping?

updated question:is there a way, i can load nibs(with its own scroll and imageview inside) as i swipe from left to right or right to left? because loading images side by side in the uiscrollview isn't going to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

this will show the image in proper aspect ... you don't have to worry about image size

```
[imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

this will keep your imageView attached to the top of scrollView.

Comment: i think it's the same thing as bottom answer. i'll try it first

Answer (score 0):

If you want every image to show at the top of the scrollView adjust the image.frame accordingly.

```
UIImageView *imageView;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:loadTheImage];

imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 480);
```

In the CGRectMake the first two values specify the padding for the image. The first is x value, the second y value. If both are 0, the image is displayed in the top left.
Does this make sense?

Comment: it does make sense. it's the way i'm doing it right now. images are at the top. but, if i scrolldown and swipe to the next image, it will show the middle portion of the image. what i wanted to do is, if i swipe, the next image will be shown automatically at the top. thanks for replying anyway, i appreciate it.

Comment: is there a way, i can load nibs(with its own scroll and imageview inside) as i swipe from left to right or right to left? because loading images side by side in the uiscrollview isn't going to do the trick.

Comment: that wouldn't work as the imageView hasn't been initialised and therefore is null.